# How to use one json file to populate another

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this function. I want to be able to use the data in the first json file to populate data in the second json file
There will be a lot of manipulation in the first json file and I dont want to repeat it in the second file.
Here is my code

```
        import xmltodict
        import pprint
        import json

        def testbobo():

                variable = "zombie"

                jsonfile = {
                                "apiStatusInfo": {
                                    "apiStatus": variable,
                                    "apiStatusCode": 100,
                                    "apiDescription": "Error with folder 'Admin'",
                                    "apiErrorCode": 404,
                                    "apiErrorDescription": [
                                        {
                                            "reason": "invalid_parameter",
                                            "name": "item",
                                            "message": "Invalid value 'd_1097790'. not found"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
               
                json_object2 = json.dumps(jsonfile, indent=4)
                print("First json file")
                print(jsonfile)
                json_object = json.loads(json_object2)

                jsonfile2 = {
                                "apiStatusInfo": {
                                    "apiStatus": json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiStatus'],
                                    "apiStatusCode": json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiStatusCode'],
                                    "apiDescription": json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiDescription'],
                                    "apiErrorCode": json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiErrorCode'],
                                    "apiErrorDescription": [
                                        {
                                            "reason":  json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiErrorDescription']['reason'],
                                            "name": json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiErrorDescription']['name'],
                                            "message": json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiErrorDescription']['message']
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }

                json_result_second = json.dumps(jsonfile2, indent=4)
                print("Second json file - must be the same with first")
                print(json_result_second)



        testbobo()
```

Everything works until I got to the apiErrorDescription section of the second json file. I was just getting this error message below

```
  "reason":  json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiErrorDescription']['reason'],
  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your json `json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiErrorDescription']` holds a list of dicts, you are trying to access it as if it were just a dict. This should work: `json_object['apiStatusInfo']['apiErrorDescription'][0]['reason']`. You will need to do that for the following two lines as well.